# Prevent duplicate entries in firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating a chat for my app with firestore, where I store chats in a separate collection. My document is structured like this:

```
{
    participant1: "kd94992nnd9",
    participant2: "49di9niso3s",
    p1Name: "...",
    p2Name: "...",
    messages: [/*messages are stored her*/],
    //Some metadata about the chats
}
```

I want to ensure that no document is created if there already exists a document with the 2 userIds. What changes do I make in my database structure to do that in firestore?

Comment: I will point out that your document structure does not scale.  The maximum size of a single document is 1MB, and if the list of messages grows large, you will not be able to add any more.  For lists of items that must be able to grow without specific bounds, they should exist as individual documents in their own collection.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware and I'm planning to make messages a subcollection of the document? Do you think that'll scale better?

Comment: It will scale near infinitely. A chat app is not likely to reach even theoretical limits.

Answer (score 3):

With Firestore, you can only guarantee uniqueness on a document ID, and not by the contents of a document's fields.  What you could do instead is concatenate the two participant IDs into a single string and use that as the document ID.  Then, you would use a [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) to ensure that a document does not already exist with that new composite ID before writing it.

Comment: I was kinda thinking of a similar solution. Problem is that 2 userIds can be concatenated in 2 ways, for example `kd94992nnd949di9niso3s` or `49di9niso3skd94992nnd9` so it will still be possible to create 2 documents for any 2 participants. How should I go about that?

Comment: Order the IDs in a predictable fashion.

Comment: I'm thinking of sorting them alphabetically :) The thing is my code has targetId and a currentId (which depends on the logged in user and the one that user wants to chat to). The order is bound to change depending on who sends the first message. What would you suggest?

Comment: Sure, you can sort them alphabetically.  Whatever works for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you store the chats in a separate collection, what do you care if there exists *earlier* chat documents?  If your structure your schema as:

```
chatRecord: {
  participants: [
    {participantID},
    {participantID},
    ...
  ],
  messages: [/* array of messages */],
  dateTag: {timestamp}
}
```

...you can trivially query on on participantIDs in the array; no particular chat document will ever get particularly large; you can sort them however you want.  You can query, sort and concatenate all the chats over any particular time period you choose, across almost any combination of participants.  The only reason NOT to store each message separately is to *possibly* reduce the number of documents read or written at a time, but I doubt that will be significant in a chat app.

Remember this is NoSQL - you are essentially *encouraged* to replicate static data, like participant names, in the separate documents for faster more efficient queries.  DRY is for SQL.  Firestore is built on the assumption that queries are so efficient that you *really* shouldn't care about the documentID, nor should you try to cram as much as possible into any single document.